# jqGrid is displaying only "IsNull" and "Is Not Null" options in search

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using `jqGrid 4.15.6-pre` with `local` datatype. I have enabled `multipleSearch: true` but I am getting only "IsNull" and "Is Not Null" as search option. Below is my code

```
 $("#dataGrid").jqGrid({
            datatype: "local",
            data: mydata,
            colNames: ['Student_ID', 'STATUS', 'TYPE', 'DESCRIPTION', 'COPIES'],
            colModel: [
                            { name: 'Student_ID', index: 'Student_ID', width: 80},
                            { name: 'STATUS', index: 'STATUS', width: 160 },
                            { name: 'TYPE', index: 'TYPE', width: 180 },
                            { name: 'DESCRIPTION', index: 'DESCRIPTION', width: 180 },
                            { name: 'COPIES', index: 'COPIES', width: 180 }
            ],
            pager: '#pagingGrid',
            sortname: 'Student_ID',
            gridview: true,
            rownumbers: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            loadonce: true,
            gridview: true,
            sortorder: "desc",
            caption: 'Just simple local grid',
            height: '100%'
        });

        $("#dataGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pagingGrid', { edit: false, add: false, del: false }, {}, {}, {}, { multipleSearch: true, closeAfterSearch: true });
```

Comment: It sound strange. Could you provide **the demo**, which reproduces the problem? I suppose that you included wrong JS files. Look at the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/4o5hsyba/ for example, which demonstrates a typical usage of Searching Dialog in free jqGrid. All search options are displayed correctly. In general one can define `sopt` array of `searchoptions` property in every column definition of `colModel` or to set common default `sopt` value. In the way you can replace default list of search option to another one (two option "IsNull" and "Is Not Null" for examples).

Comment: @Oleg Yes, the issue was of the reference, once I referred the files as per your fiddle, it worked like charm..Thanks..I have one more query here..Can I export the JqGrid into excel in free version?

Comment: @Oleg Thanks again ..Excel worked too!! Do we have similar ones for PDF and Print ?

Comment: jqGrid has no such functionality. I'd recommend you to export to Excel and use printing/pdf-writing functionality of Excel. It has many helpful printing features which can't be easy implemented. Alternatively you can use any other open source product which can help to generate PDF files from JavaScript, like (isPDF)[https://parall.ax/products/jspdf] for example. The idea is the same as in case of using SheetJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sound strange. Could you provide the demo, which reproduces the problem? I suppose that you included wrong JS files. Look at the demo `https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/4o5hsyba/` for example, which demonstrates a typical usage of Searching Dialog in free jqGrid. All search options are displayed correctly. In general, one can define `sopt` array of `searchoptions` property in every column definition of `colModel` or to set common default `sopt` value. In the way you can replace default list of search option to another one (two option "IsNull" and "Is Not Null" for examples).